# Не работает cvWriteFrame

Tags: winforms, opencv

Помогите разобраться почему не работает программа для записи видео с экрана.Программа компилируется,но при запуске выскакивает исключение System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException" в приложении ЗАГОТОВКА_OpenCV_WF.exe

Дополнительные сведения: Внешний компонент создал исключение.

В стеке вызовов: "указанные ниже фреймы могут быть неверны и(или) отсутствовать,символы для opencv_core220d.dll не загружены"

Проверяю frame - через cvShowImage( "original", frame ) - все в порядке.А записываться он не хочет. Вот код

```css
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
 
     
 const char *filename = "C:\\Users\\валера\\Pictures\\Video.avi";
 
 
     Graphics^ graph;   
  Bitmap^ bitmap;
  //cvNamedWindow("original",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
   bitmap = gcnew Bitmap (Screen::PrimaryScreen->Bounds.Width,Screen::PrimaryScreen->Bounds.Height);  
   CvSize size = cvSize(Screen::PrimaryScreen->Bounds.Width, Screen::PrimaryScreen->Bounds.Height);
  
  CvVideoWriter *writer = cvCreateVideoWriter(filename, CV_FOURCC('D','I','V','X'), 25, size, 1);
       
  
  assert(writer!=0);  
   while(true){
  
  
    graph = Graphics::FromImage(bitmap);  
   graph->CopyFromScreen(0,0,0,0,bitmap->Size); 
System::Drawing::Rectangle Rect(0,0,bitmap->Width,bitmap->Height);
   
  Bitmap ^ bitmap1 = bitmap->Clone(Rect, Imaging::PixelFormat::Format32bppRgb);


     System::Drawing::Imaging::BitmapData^ bmData = bitmap->LockBits(
   System::Drawing::Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap1->Width, bitmap1->Height) ,
   System::Drawing::Imaging::ImageLockMode::ReadWrite,bitmap1-> PixelFormat);
  
      frame = cvCreateImage(cvSize(bitmap1->Width , bitmap1->Height) , IPL_DEPTH_8U , 4);
  frame->imageData = (char*)bmData->Scan0.ToPointer();
   cvNamedWindow("original",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);  
             
  
  cvWriteFrame(writer, frame);
     // cvShowImage( "original", frame );

      cvWaitKey(5);
   bitmap->UnlockBits(bmData);
   }
      cvReleaseCapture( &capture );
    cvReleaseVideoWriter(&writer);
       // cvDestroyWindow("capture");
   
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Поменял 32bppRgb на 24bppRgb и число каналов в cvCreateImage на 3 и проблема исчезла.Хотя есть другие проблемы,но пока не буду просить помощи.Попробую разобраться сам

Comment: Примите ответ (галочка слева).